# Using a DEM to identify areas that are below the surrounding ground by a given value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, spatial-analyst, focal-statistics

In ArcGIS 10.1 (advanced license) I have a bare-earth DEM (5m cell size) and I would like to identify depressions which at least, say, 4 meters below the surrounding ground.

What I have tried is to use *Focal Statistic* to produce a smoothed DEM representing the average elevation within a given moving window, and then subtracting that from the original DEM in order to spot negative areas (=depressions). The problem is that the smoothed DEM so obtained is biased toward high elevations, since (needless to say) them mean is "pulled" toward high elevation values. Therefore, I got not conclusive results.

Edit:
I found a solution myself, and I will post the answers in case someone will jump here in the future.

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: I did not try yet. I was just wondering if that makes sense. Thank you for replying. Looking forward to comments/suggestions.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor or workflow reviewer.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I will rephrase my question to better express my doubts and the issue with the results I get.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. First, I used the 'Fill' tool (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/fill.htm). Then, I took the tool’s output raster and I subtracted it from the original DEM. What I got was a raster representing "pits" (cavities) featuring, needless to say, negative elevation values. Finally, I reclassified the raster to break the values down into some meaninful classes.